# MDX SET within Measures axis

Tags: ssas, mdx

In MDX, is it possible create a Named Sets when including with the Measures Axis eg

```
WITH
  SET [MyFields] AS (
    IIF((IsEmpty([Measures].[MeasureField])), null,
      IIF(([School].[Key].CurrentMember IS [School].[Key].&[9999] or [School].[Key].CurrentMember IS [School].[Key].&[8888])
        ,{[Measures].[MeasureField]}
        ,IIF(([Semester].[Key].CurrentMember IS [Semester].[Key].&[1])
          ,{[Measures].[MeasureField]}
          ,null
        )
      )    
    )
  )
  SET [MyNonEmpty] AS (
    NonEmpty(
      {([Student].[UniqueId].[UniqueId].members,({ [School].[Key].&[9999], [School].[Key].&[8888] })
    )
  )
SELECT {
  MyFields
} ON COLUMNS
,NON EMPTY { (
  MyNonEmpty
  * [Dim1].[Field1].[Field1].ALLMEMBERS
  * [Dim2].[Field2].[Field2].ALLMEMBERS
  ...
}
...
```

Although I can use a Calculated Member on the Dimensions (COLUMNS above) axis (and successfully return rows), the above syntax which uses the Named SET in the Measures (ROWS) axis, returns no rows (and no error).

Just a note - in the the above example no rows are returned regardless of whether MyFields is empty or non-empty

Comment: Could you include the exact MDX used in "some calculation"?

Comment: Calculation has been added to original query - could it be the IIF statement - I've been reading IIF should be avoided in SET operations "The IIf function is not recommended for creating a set of members based on search criteria. Instead, use the Filter function to evaluate each member in a specified set against a logical expression and return a subset of members." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/iif-mdx?view=sql-analysis-services-2017

Comment: What's in the WHERE clause? The set gets evaluated once at the beginning of the query ok the context of the where clause. So if your where clause mentions one of those `IS` conditions then it may make a difference.

Comment: What are you trying to get it to do? Do you want the `IIf` functions to get evaluated on every row?

Comment: I could create a Calculated Member for the above however, I want the column to come in with the same name (we have logic to receive the field under the specific name which is used across a number of calls) - i.e.[Measures].[MeasureField] - if I created a calculated member it would come in with a different name

Comment: I don't get it. Your IIf statement only returns MeasureField. What should cause it to return a different measure?

Comment: I don't have a WHERE clause but there is another Named SET (I've updated the query) - note [Dim3].[Key] is used in both Named SET's - from what you are saying, will one affect the other ?

Comment: I believe the NonEmpty function in MyNonEmpty will return any combinations for which `[Measures].DefaultMember` is not empty. I would recommend you describe how it should work.

Comment: In reference to the Calculated Member - it will be a different name in that the result set returned will need to refer to it under the Calculated Member name (which has to be different to the original field name - otherwise the error message "The 'MeasureField' calculated member cannot be created because a member with the same name already exists" will appear

Comment: I've updated the query to include more meaningful names School.Key, Student.UniqueId, Semester.Key - I'm wanting details about students that have moved to/from schools 8888/9999 - this works well.  There is a further condition (which is covered by the MyFields Named SET) - if the student moved *to* schools 8888/9999 show both the semester 1 and 2 records - however if the student moved *from* schools 8888/9999 then only show semester 1.  And as mentioned if I put the MyFields in a Calculated Member I get exactly what I'm wanting, however if I use the Named Set strategy as outlined I get nothing

Comment: You can use a *SCOPE* assignment to define specific values for `[Measures].[MeasureField]` calculated measure. By doing this you retain calc measure name and define specific values according to your needs.